# How to create multidimensional array based on ID from each row (in same View) Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter both php, I am beginner. Could anyone help me how to show a data from another table based on ID in each row in same View in codeigniter, i just include a file(that is a form with data from another table) im not sure.. how the method should be.. dont know what to do plz ! thx

CONTROLLER

```html
$this->load->model('m_work_order');
$this->load->model('m_srv_product');

$data['items']     =  $this->m_work_order->show_items()->result();

$id=0; // dont know what to do with this ID
$data1['record']     =  $this->m_srv_product->show_data($id)->result_array();

$data['form'] = $this->load->view('work_order/form_file', $data1, TRUE);
$this->load->view('work_order/form_input',$data);
```

MODEL m_work_order

```html
function show_items(){

$query  =      "SELECT *
                FROM work_order_items 
                WHERE item_status='0'";
                return $this->db->query($query);

}
```

MODEL m_srv_product

```html
function show_data($id)
{


    $query= "SELECT a.srv_pr_id,a.srv_vol,a.srv_n,
            b.srv_name,c.prod_cat_name,c.prod_cat_id
                FROM srv_pr_use as a,service as b, prod_category as c
                WHERE a.srv_id = b.srv_id and 
                a.prod_cat_id = c.prod_cat_id and
                a.srv_id = $id ";
                return $this->db->query($query);
}
```

VIEW

```html
foreach ($items as $t){
        
echo "
      <tr>
        <td>$no</td>
        <td>$kode</td>
        <td>$t->item_name</td>
        <td>$t->item_qty</td>
        <td>".$form."</td>
        </tr>"
}
```

Comment: make a example with tables for better explain...and there are a lot of link with multidimesional examples.

Comment: @felixmpa yes i did.. but still cant solve this.. Do you mean my Table structure ?